# Accessing element in custom array wrapper via overloading operator []

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to implement my own array wrapper. I overloaded [] operators that returns address of element in array. However when I dynamically allocate the ArrayWrapper class in main, it is not working.

**Why is it not working?** **Is it because variable arr is a pointer?**

I get these errors:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka
>   std::basic_ostream}' lvalue to
>   'std::basic_ostream&&'  Cviceni.cpp /Cviceni/src    line 25 C/C++
>   Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type no match for 'operator<<'
>   (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and
>   'ArrayWrapper')   Cviceni.cpp /Cviceni/src    line 25 C/C++ Problem

**Working code**

```
    ArrayWrapper arr(250);

 try
 {
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.getSize(); i++)
   {
     arr[i] = i + 1;
     cout << arr[i] << endl;
   }
}
catch(std::range_error& e)
  {
      cout << e.what() << endl;
  }

  cout << "End..." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Not working code:**

```
ArrayWrapper *arr = new ArrayWrapper(250);

  try
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr->getSize(); i++)
    {
      arr[i] = i + 1;
      cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
  }
```

**ArrayWrapper implementation:**

```
class ArrayWrapper
{
private:
  int size;
  int *elements;

public:
  ArrayWrapper(int n) : size(n), elements(new int[n])
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      elements[i] = 0;
  };

  ~ArrayWrapper(){delete []elements;};

  int& operator[](int i)
  {
    if(i >= size || i < 0)
      {
    throw range_error("Out of range");
      }
    return elements[i];
  };

  int getSize(){ return size;};
};
```

Comment: Copy-paste the error message into the question itself.

Comment: Just change `cout << arr[i] << endl;` to `cout << (*arr)[i] << endl;`. you should not mess around with a pointer for that case at all.

Comment: Also [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three); *"I overloaded [] operators that returns address of element in array."* - no, it returns a reference. And you wouldn't need to check for negative numbers if you used `size_t` for indexing and sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that you are using pointer in the second example
`arr[2]` is not an operation on ArrayWrapper it's operation on pointer.

```
ArrayWrapper *arr = new ArrayWrapper(250);

  try
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr->getSize(); i++)
    {
      (*arr)[i] = i + 1;
      cout << (*arr)[i] << endl;
    }
  }
```